# Spring Batch: reading from a database and being aware of the previous processed id?

Tags: spring-data, spring-batch

I'm trying to setup `Spring Batch` to move DB records from `Oracle` to `Cassandra` daily.

I know I can manually define JPA repository queries based on additional entity table (like MyBatchProgress where I store previously completed `Id` + date or something like that), so that the next batch job knows which entity to start with for further operations.

My question is: does Spring Batch provide something like this inbuilt (also by utilising Spring Data JPA)?

Or is this something that I have to write manually in the job reader step where I just pick up the `last Id` stored in my custom "progress" table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to save the last processed id somewhere (in a database table) if this is required each time you run the job so the job knows where it should start from.  Assuming you're job is triggered from a timer, the timer could lookup that id value and launch the job, passing the last processed id as a job parameter.

Comment: @httPants that is something I am currently doing manually. I thought this was something trivial and would be included in Spring Batch. The problem I have is that the *Reader interface has a single entity as a param, whilest the *Writer accepts a list. I am not sure how Spring Batch would write that last ID of the last record it manipulated and if read step would pick it up correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the last ID in the execution context, which is persisted in the meta-data tables. With that in place, you can make the code that launches the job look for the last job execution, take the ID from its context and pass it as a job parameter to the next job instance.

Comment: thanks! what about if I want to know the ID of the previous transaction inside the job. There can be 1....n of transactions inside a job. I need to query that transaction. I could use Spring Batch inbuilt IdIncrementor(), but I am not sure if that fully suits my needs.

Comment: What do you mean by the ID of the previous transaction and query that transaction? Which transaction are you referring to? The storage mechanism you where looking for is the execution context in my opinion (unless you want to store progress data elsewhere), so you can put whatever you want in the context and use it as needed to launch the next execution.

Comment: ID of the previous transaction = id of the previously processed entity / unit / item inside a specific step. My opinion was that spring batch stores values inside context that are a result of the whole step and not something that can be stored inside a step as being the progress of the step...

Comment: There are two levels of execution contexts: step execution context and job execution context. Both are persisted in the database (in different tables). It is up to you to choose where to store the info you need for the next run.

Comment: ok, then step execution context if persisted also during step execution could be the very thing that I need! thank you!